# Paypal has red lock by https?

Tags: encryption

[image: http://imgur.com/aMgsdE6]

This is what paypal says when I log in near the top left near https://. 
Is this ok?

Comment: Which browser you are using?

Comment: Are you using a corporate LAN?

Answer (score 3):

The worrying part is that the page includes resources which are not secure. Since this does not happen for me I don't expect a fault by Paypal itself. This can also not be done by a man in the middle attack so I expect the problem inside the browser. I expect that you have a browser extension which causes this problems.

Such extension can be innocent and still cause such errors but it can also be harmful (i.e. man in the browser attack). Note that in the past seemingly innocent extensions [turned to the bad site later](http://arstechnica.com/security/2014/01/malware-vendors-buy-chrome-extensions-to-send-adware-filled-updates/). Such a browser extension has full access to the page and could modify it or just grab the data (password) you enter. Therefore I would recommend to disable any extensions you have (only reinstalling the browser will not necessarily help) and also to change your access credentials for Paypal before an attacker uses these.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the picture, the good things are:

- the website has an [Extended Validation Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate) which is good.
- It uses TLS 1.2 which is the latest and is recommended.

the bad stuff:

- the Certificate may have been expired or revoked due to various reasons. (could also happen due to wrong time configured at the client)
- Even though TLS1.2 is used, either your Browser or OS does not have Cipher Suites to make a secure enough connection.(I suspect [the weaker CBC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/how-can-cipher-block-chaining-cbc-in-ssl-be-attacked) is causing it )

What can you do about this?

- this connection is not safe enough for transactions so I recommend against sending any sensitive information through this connection.
- Update your web browser to the latest version and see if you still get these messages.
- Try a different web browser and see if it makes a difference
- Check if you have the right Date and time configured in your operating system.
- Update your Operating system with the latest patches

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not logging in.
Clear your browser cache and restart your browser, it should fix the issue.

Comment: I already logged in

Comment: log-out, clear your cache, restart your browser, log back in (provided there are no insecure scripts loaded) and change your password.